# WebSocket broadcast to all clients using Python

Tags: python, websocket, stream, chat, broadcast

I am using a simple Python based web socket application:

```
from SimpleWebSocketServer import WebSocket, SimpleWebSocketServer

class SimpleEcho(WebSocket):

    def handleMessage(self):

        if self.data is None:
            self.data = ''

        # echo message back to client
        self.sendMessage(str(self.data))

    def handleConnected(self):
        print self.address, 'connected'

    def handleClose(self):
        print self.address, 'closed'

server = SimpleWebSocketServer('', 8000, SimpleEcho)
server.serveforever()
```

It echoes messages sent by each client to the same individual client, but I I am trying to send any message received by the ws server to all clients connected to it. Can someone help me please?

Comment: You want chat with websocket. It is helloworld in websocket world and it is easy to find with google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you could do this:

```
class SimpleEcho(WebSocket):

    def handleMessage(self):
        if self.data is None:
            self.data = ''

        for client in self.server.connections.itervalues():
            client.sendMessage(str(self.address[0]) + ' - ' + str(self.data))

        #echo message back to client
        #self.sendMessage(str(self.data))

    def handleConnected(self):
        print self.address, 'connected'

    def handleClose(self):
        print self.address, 'closed'
```

Comment: Actually I did this and it turned out to be a better solution than the previous. That one crashes because of array management

Comment: But using loops isn't a good way I guess. If we have more clients(more values in array), then the message will be delayed to the last clients. It can be some negligible difference. But say if you want to send the time for all the clients connected at once, then you can find the milli-seconds difference.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to create a list clients and then progamatically send a message to each of them.

So, when a new client connects, add them to an array:

```
wss = [] # Should be globally scoped

def handleConnected(self):
    print self.address, 'connected'
    if self not in wss:
        wss.append(self)
```

Then, when you get a new request, send the message out to each of the clients stored:

```
def handleMessage(self):
    if self.data is None:
        self.data = ''

    for ws in wss:
        ws.sendMessage(str(self.data))
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Awesome James! That works exactly the way I want it. You are the best!

Answer (score 1):

Add this to remove if a client disconnects so the array is not full of not connected people

```
def handleClose(self):
    wss.remove(self)
```