# Server not broadcasting to clients

Tags: python, websocket

I am attempting to use the code supplied in the answer to [WebSocket broadcast to all clients using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29871360/websocket-broadcast-to-all-clients-using-python) in order to broadcast messages to all connected clients, but the code never even seems to enter the for loop.  I don't get any errors, but nothing goes across the LAN, even though there are connected clients.

```
        print()
        print("1 -", ReturnStatus)
        if ReturnStatus:
            print("2 - Sending Data", MessageText)
            for client in self.server.connections.itervalues():
                print("3 -", client, MessageText, self.address)
                client.sendMessage(MessageText)
```

stdout from server:

```
1 - True
2 - Sending Data Line, 4, Heat

1 - True
2 - Sending Data Control,  3

1 - True
2 - Sending Data Control,  2

1 - True
2 - Sending Data Control,  3

1 - True
2 - Sending Data Line, 3, Remote

1 - True
2 - Sending Data Line, 3, Outside
```

Note the absence of the print values inside the for loop.

Additional note: I put in a try block with the following results:

```
            try:
                for client in clients:
                    print(client)
            except Exception as e:
                print("Exception {}".format(e))
```

with the result:

```
Exception name 'clients' is not defined
```

and then:

```
            try:
                for client in self.server.connections.itervalues():
                    client.sendMessage(MessageText)
```

with the result:

```
Exception 'dict' object has no attribute 'itervalues'
```

It may be significant to note the Python version is 3.5.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer.  Evidently Python3 has removed itervalues.  Here is the working code:

```
            for client in self.server.connections.values():
                client.send_message(MessageText)
```